# Voice recognition/identification

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I've been searching around for some time now, and all i can find about voice recognition is voice to text typing.
Does anyone know if there's a way to recognize a users voice to trigger a command, that would'nt be triggered if someone else repeated the same command.

Any directions or useful keywords about how/where to find info on this subject is appreciated.

EDIT:
voice prints lead to MARF(Modular Audio Recognition Framework).

Comment: You'll want to look up voiceprints and realize that this is much more indepth than speech to text.

Comment: I was figuring something like that, but i've got a lot of spare hours to spend on this :D

Comment: Hi there, Are you able to use MARF successfully please share your thoughts here ???

Comment: Sorry to say this project, due to being a sparetime project, has been postponed. I'll update the question if/when i make any progress on this